# php session_start header already sent encoding utf-8 issue

Tags: php, session, error-handling

I am having following error, while nothing is output before session_start function:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /xyz_path/index.php:1) in /xyz_path/index.php on line 2
```

the code is following:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Application Jersey</title>
```

I have tried this code as well and the error is same, but session id is available:

```
<?php
if(!session_start()){
    session_start();
}
echo session_id();
?>
```

Comment: There's probably a whitespace before the start php tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: are you sure no other file is run before this one? Also you need to check for even a single white space or a line before session_start()

Comment: Also, make sure there is no document BOM. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: `if (!session_start()) session_start()` does not mean *"if the session isn't started, start the session."* Instead if just tries to start the session twice.

Comment: @deceze it means calling session_start() twice is starting session with the error in my case, while only once it is not even printing session_id();

Comment: My file was UTF-8 encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that it happened on line 2, which says that either

- you have an empty line at the top, or
- there's an invisible character sent

if it's the second, make sure to change the encoding of the file in your code editor to anything that doesn't have BOM in its name.

some editors add BOM byte at the beginning of UTF(8, 16) encoded files.

Comment: I have enabled show all symbols but there is no line or space.

Comment: It says this file start with BOM, thanks it resolved my issue no more erros.

Comment: I just set myfile from "UTF-8" to "UTF-8 without BOM", I am using Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php 
ob_start(); // add this line
session_start(); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Application Jersey</title>
```

This works for me.

Comment: @justnajm what you get explain after using it.

Answer (score 0):

On linux you could use the command:

```
cat -A 'filename'
```

or

```
cat -A 'filename' | less
```

it will show

```
M-oM-;M-?<?php$
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with following Code

```
<?php session_start(); ob_start(); ?>
```

Replace First Line Of Your Code with above line.

Comment: Starting output buffering *after* you have tried to set a header which failed because you did it *after* output has already been output is pointless. It only "works fine" if there was no problematic output to begin with.